# How to phrase a select statement to be that if a certain attribute attains a certain domain value; select values where it does not exist

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I want to display the result of a value where that value meets the criteria: the result has to show the person that does not lecture in the course 'AS' and then along that name also show his/her tel number. The natural language format that im thinking of is select distinct namn, tel from table where if namn has nickname value'AS', dot not show that namn. select distinct namn, tel from finalver2 where nickname <> 'AS'; Lisens name will still appear as she also has a masters class and I do not want her name to appear.

The result should look like this:

```
namn       tel
Faramarz   1054
```

The result above should be retrieved from the following scenario:

```
nickname    kkod        namn        sport       ford        tel
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
eGOV        TIG098      Lisen       Fotboll     Cykel       1076
AS          TIG162      Lisen       Fotboll     Cykel       1076
AS          TIG162      Lisen       Fotboll     Cykel       1076
AS          TIG162      Lisen       Fotboll     Cykel       1076
BSS         TIG163      Faramarz    Fotboll     Cykel       1054
BSS         TIG163      Faramarz    Fotboll     Cykel       1054
BSS         TIG163      Faramarz    Fotboll     Cykel       1054
BSS         TIG163      Faramarz    Fotboll     Cykel       1054
Masters     TIA019      Lisen       Fotboll     Cykel       1076
```

How should I phrase the select statement? Appriciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by` teacher name, and filter with `having` clause on those that never lectured the `'AS'` course.

```
select naam, tel
from mytable
group by nanm, tel
having max(nickname = 'AS') = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is not to filter out the very rows you need when trying to select the ones that don't match.  Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT profs.namn, profs.tel
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT namn, tel FROM Courses) as profs
LEFT JOIN Courses c ON profs.namn = c.namn AND c.nickname = 'AS'
WHERE c.namn IS NULL
```

The sub-query (profs) gives you a list of each professor and their telephone number, without duplicates (note, if they are listed with more than one telephone number, you'll get them separately with each telephone number).  This is then LEFT JOINed with the entire table to pair each professor with their courses, but the ON clause also restricts those matches to the course you wish to exclude (you could also use IN and a list of multiple values), so only those professors who do not teach the 'AS' class (or any of the IN list, if you use that) will fail to match the ON clause and result in NULL values for the c table in the result of the outer join.

The WHERE clause is applied after the outer join is computed and selects just the ones that have NULL values, in other words those that do not teach the specified class(es).  The DISTINCT in the outer SELECT might not be necessary.  The placement of conditions in the WHERE or particular ON clauses is significant when using outer joins.

There might be other ways to do it; I'm not sure if this is the best, but I think it would work.  There's probably a way to do it with Count, GROUP BY and HAVING, but I think it ends up about the same complexity (with a very similar structure) and not quite as flexible.

Comment: Got it! On the other hand, I find the where, group by, having, order by structure to be quite neat and beginner friendly so to say. Your script their worked fine, it gave me the desired results; however, I think the language of it is a bit hard for me as of now (im just a beginner).

Comment: Yeah, the other answer does seem cleaner.  I think their HAVING clause is using a syntax that might be newer than what I'm familiar with, but that's a handy approach if it works.  My approach might teach you some tricks that could come in handy in other cases.  Don't be afraid to break out parts of it or tweak it to see if you can work out why it works.